# How to return binary array in django-rest framewrok?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, django-rest-framework

I am working on the server-client web service.

I want the server to download the file from a url and return the raw byte of the content of the file.

However, it seems that the received bytes from ajax is corrputed.

Here is the server side:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
import urllib2
class MyView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        url = request.DATA['url']
        conn = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        byte = conn.read()
        conn.close()
        return Response({'blob':byte})
```

Here is the client side,

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'myurl',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        "url": url,
    }),                        
    success: function(response, textStatus, jqXhr) {
    if (response) {
        try {
            var blob=response.blob;
            // process blob, but it is corrupted
         } catch (e) {
            displayError(e);
     }

     },
     error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         var err = parseError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
         displayError(err);
     }
});
```

What is the proper way to do this with django-rest framework?

Thank you!